# Ruby on Rails 3.1 - How to populate crontab / cronjob dynamically on a daily basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, background, cron

I have a ruby task that downloads some data from a third party on a daily basis. 
Based on this downloaded data, I want to update the crontab.

For instance, at 9 AM every morning, I want to decide the list of scheduled tasks for the day.

Today, 9 AM - I know that "TASK A" needs to run at 1 PM and 2 PM. So, I need to insert crontab for 1 PM and 2 PM.

Tomorrow, 9 AM - I will know that "TASK A" needs to run at 4 PM. So, I need to insert crontab for 4 PM.

How can I achieve this ? Any recommended gems ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have a look at the whenever gem, and write a schedule.rb in the initializers file (it's the whenever config file). After that update the crontab with the whenever command.

https://github.com/javan/whenever

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Comment: I was going to also suggest the `whenever` gem, but I would, in addition, recommend that @user1000589 restructures the way he/she generates tasks (or.. see further). With the information provided, the algorithm for determining which tasks run remains unclear..

Comment: Basically, I download a TV schedule once a day. Whenever I get a new schedule, I want to start the recorder for the show times I have downloaded.

Comment: So, my cronjob will need to have an entry for show start time.

The task is to start the recorder (would mostly be a rake task).

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but I asked a similar question the other day and was recommend to try [CronEdit](http://cronedit.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Whenever gem
# In rails 4
require File.expand_path('../..//config/environment.rb', __FILE__)

# This is your table by which you will get your new value 
bid_update = DynamicOfferTime.first

# Now Task As
every (bid_update.hour_value).hours do
  puts "This will repeat in every #{bid_update.hour_value} hour"
end
```